# setExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE) and setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) giving error

Tags: android, android-geofence

In my method for building a geofence, I am getting an error on `ExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE)` and `setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)` stating that they can't be resolved to a variable. Why is this happening?

## My method:

```
private void buildGeofence(){
    LatLng geofencePoint = marker.getPosition();
    int radius = 1610;
    Geofence.Builder geofence = new Geofence.Builder();
    geofence.setCircularRegion(geofencePoint.latitude,geofencePoint.longitude, radius);
    geofence.setExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE);
    geofence.setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);
    geofence.setNotificationResponsiveness(0);
    geofence.build();
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yeah, so I forgot to declare the constants. Duh! Here's the declarations I used:

```
long NEVER_EXPIRE = -1;
int GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER = 1;
```

More on the matter here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html

Comment: You should use the constants defined in Geofence (as @stefan has stated) and not define your own.Your app could break if the values of the constants were updated in a later version of Android.

Comment: You don't need to declare the constants because they're already declared in the library, but you do need to reference the library constants in a way that java can tell what you're referencing.

Presumably you have `import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;` at the top, so you can reference the library's constants as `Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE` and `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER`

Answer (score 9):

Those constants are already declared in the Geofence Class you reference, so jut use them as `geofence.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);`